# How do you switch skills quickly without changing your weapon in hand? (Diablo II)

Tags: diablo-ii

I'm a Paladin in Diablo II, and I want to know how it's possible to switch skills really quick. I'm using Blessed Hammer in my second set of gear, and that's for attack. The first set is for defending and healing. So, I want to know how to use Defiance and Cleansing whenever I want a certain one, so if I just want defense, I use Defiance, but Cleansing is for healing and getting rid of poison.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fastest way to switch skills in Diablo 2 is to use the mouse wheel or direction function key. In order to do this, you have to assign skills to your F keys and then you'll be able to switch to them in order of what you have assigned.

For example:

- Open up your quick list of spells (default S key)
- Hover over the skill you want to assign with your mouse to F1 and click F1
- This will have now assigned the skill to your F1 key
- Continue to do this for any number of skills you want to do
- Now you have the option to actually press the function key to jump straight to the skill or use the mouse wheel to cycle through your skills in order

Alternatively, with Diablo 2: Resurrected, since Patch 2.3, you can activate "Quick Cast" from the game options, which enables the activating of the spell/ability on function button press immediately, without to need to click left/right mouse button (default button)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I just didn't know you had to hover over something to do it. :D